# Read fixed range of rows from a 20GB csv file using R

Tags: r, csv

I have a laptop with 4 gigs of RAM and I am trying to read a 20 GB file using the `read.csv.ffdf` command of the `ff` package in R....

```
read.csv.ffdf(file="transactions.csv", header=TRUE, 
              VERBOSE=TRUE, nrows=20000, colClasses=NA)
```

I can read rows starting from 1  to whatever no. I wish which is not a problem but I am not able to set specific no. of rows  as arguments in this command... like I want to read no. of rows starting from 10000 to 20000... please suggest some other command where I can set the no. of row to start with...

Comment: the default `FUN` argument is `read.table` which takes a `skip` argument.

Comment: There is info about that in the "Notes" section of the help page but i'm not entirely sure what they are suggesting: "Note that using the 'skip' argument still requires to read the file from beginning in order to count the lines to be skipped. If you first read part of the file in order to understand its structure and then want to continue, a more efficient solution that using 'skip' is opening a file connection and pass that to argument 'file'. read.table.ffdf does the same in order to skip efficiently over previously read chunks."

Comment: @Richard : Thanx for the answer ... It works but I am able to see just 1000 rows in the console...! Is it that 10000 rows get read but it shows only 1000 rows...? or is there any problem
Also will this work for 10 Million rows at once....?

Comment: @ShreedharPawar, you should just increase `nrows` to the number that you need